# See progress of lvm --merge

Tags: lvm, snapshot

Is there any way I can see the progress of a merge of my snapshot back to the origin?

The only thing I know is that there is an ongoing merge because I can't create a new snapshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running lvconvert, use the *interval* flag. From the man page:

> -i, --interval Seconds
>
> Report progress as a percentage at regular intervals.

Comment: And if I didn't do that? No way to see it then? Or even abort it? As far as I can tell it's not doing any progress and I can't abort it.

Comment: I don't know. You could ask on the linux-lvm mailing list. https://sourceware.org/lvm2/

Comment: `lvs -a`: Data% columns will go down to 0% while merging

Answer (score 0):

run

```
watch -n 1 "ps auxf | grep lvm | grep -v grep"
```

And check to see if the time column is going up. If it is you know the program is using CPU time.

Comment: Try `ps auxf | grep [l]vm` for an easy hack that removes the need for `grep -v`.